# Questions regarding prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype

How does the prototype method work?

```
var object, u1, u2;
object = function(o) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
u1 = {'name': 'adam'};
u2 = object(u1);
u2.name = 'roman';
delete u1.name;
console.log(u2.name);
delete u2.name;
console.log(u2.name);
u1.name = 'tytus';
console.log(u2.name);

roman
undefined
titus
```

Why is the third console.log being output? Could you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the way JS resolves references, or evaluates expressions. What is happening is similar to this:

```
u2[name] ===> JS checks instance for property name<------------||
    || --> property not found @instance, check prototype (u1)  ||
    ===========> u1.name was found, return its value ----------||
         ||
         || if it weren\'t found here:
         ==========> Object.prototype.name: not found check prototype?
             ||
             =======>prototype of object.prototype is null, return undefined
```

When you log `u2.name` the first time round, `name` was an instance property, so JS resolved the expression to that string constant (`roman`). Then you deleted it, so upon trying to access it again, JS resolved to `u1.name` (`u2`'s prototype), which also didn't have the `name` property, nor did it find `Object.prototype.name`, hence the expression was resolved to `undefined`.

In the third case, the same steps were repeated, only this time the prototype of `u2` *did* have a `name` property, so that's what the expression was resolved to. It's as simple as that, really. 
Ok, to be fair, it took me some time to get used to this, too, but once you get it, it's pure logic.

BTW, the diagram I made here is a visual representation of what is referred to as *"the prototype-chain"*. From the viewpoint of `u2`, the chain is `u1 -> Object`, which isn't a very large chain at all (in case you were worried): it's very similar to the chain of an `Array` instance:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype));//Logs Object
```

Hence, the prototype chain of an array instance, say `var foo = [];`) looks like this:

```
Array.prototype => Object.prototype
```

Which means that:

```
foo = []
foo[123];//does not exists
```

Triggers a similar lookup through the prototype chain in order for the expression to resolve to `undefined`:

```
foo[123] ===> 123 is coerced to string first BTW  <------------||
    || --> property not found @instance, check Array.prototype ||
    ===========> Array.prototype[123] not found                ||
         ||                                                    ||
         ==========> no Object.prototype[123]: check prototype ||
             ||                                                ||
             =======>prototype of object.prototype is null, return undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is an object oriented programming language. However unlike other object oriented languages like C++ and Python it doesn't have classes. Instead JavaScript has prototypal inheritance.

In prototypal object oriented programming languages you only have objects. Inheritance is achieved via one of two ways:

1. [Delegation](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#delegation_or_differential_inheritance)
2. [Concatenation](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#cloning_or_concatenative_inheritance)

Suppose I have an object called `rectangle` as follows:

```
var rectangle = {
    height: 5,
    width: 10,
    area: function () {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }
};
```

Now I can calculate the area of this rectangle by calling `rectangle.area`. However what if I wanted to create another rectangle with a different `width` and `height`? This is where your `object` function is used (this function is available natively in most JavaScript interpreters as [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)):

```
var rectangle2 = Object.create(rectangle);

rectangle2.height = 10;
rectangle2.width = 20;

alert(rectangle2.area()); // 200
```

What's happening here is that the object `rectangle2` is inheriting from the object `rectangle` via delegation. To help you visualize what's happening look at the following diagram:

```
                null
                 ^
                 | [[Proto]]
                 |
 +-------------------------------+
 |        Object.prototype       |
 +-------------------------------+
 |              ...              |
 +-------------------------------+
                 ^
                 | [[Proto]]
                 |
 +-------------------------------+
 |           rectangle           |
 +-------------------------------+
 |           height: 5           |
 +-------------------------------+
 |           width: 10           |
 +-------------------------------+
 |           area: ...           |
 +-------------------------------+
                 ^
                 | [[Proto]]
                 |
 +------------------------------+
 |          rectangle2          |
 +------------------------------+
 |          height: 10          |
 +------------------------------+
 |          width:  20          |
 +------------------------------+
```

The `Object.create` function creates an object (`rectangle2`) whose internal `[[Proto]]` property points to the object `rectangle` (the prototype of `rectangle2`).

When you try to access a property on `rectangle2` JavaScript first tries to find the property on `rectangle2` itself. If it can't find the property on `rectangle2` then it tries to find it on the prototype of `rectangle2` (i.e. `rectangle`) and so on until:

1. It find the property, in which case it returns the value associated with that property.
2. It exhausts the prototype chain (i.e. it reaches `null`), in which case it returns `undefined`.

Hence if I try to access `rectangle2.width` it will return `20`. However if I try to access `rectangle2.area` it will return the `rectangle.area` function instead of `undefined`. That's prototypal inheritance for you in a nutshell.

---

Now in you code you first create an object `u1`:

```
var u1 = {
    name: "adam"
};
```

Then you create an object `u2` which inherits from `u1`:

```
var u2 = Object.create(u1);
```

After that you set a new `name` property on `u2` (this doesn't overwrite the `name` property of `u1`, it simply shadows it):

```
u2.name = "roman";
```

Then you delete the `name` property of `u1` (this doesn't affect the name property of `u2`):

```
delete u1.name;
```

So when you log `u2.name` it displays `roman`:

```
console.log(u2.name); // roman
```

Then you delete the `name` property of `u2` as well:

```
delete u2.name;
```

Hence when you log `u2.name` again it displays `undefined`:

```
console.log(u2.name); // undefined
```

Finally you set `u1.name` to `tytus`:

```
u1.name = "tytus";
```

Hence when you log `u2.name` again it displays `tytus` because `u2` delegates to `u1`:

```
console.log(u2.name); // tytus
```

I hope this helped you understand prototypal inheritance. If you want to learn more then read my blog post on [Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters).

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access a property of an object, JavaScript first checks if the actual object has that property and if not, it checks if the prototype of its constructor function has that property:

```
var object, u1, u2;
object = function(o) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};

//u1 is just a "normal" JavaScript Object, created by the Object constructor function
u1 = {'name': 'adam'};
//u2 is an object, that was created by a custom constructor function (F) with the prototype u1
u2 = object(u1);

//add a local property "name" to u2
u2.name = 'roman';

//delete the property "name" from u1 (and thereby from the prototype of u2)
delete u1.name;

//prints "roman" because u2 has a local property "name"
console.log(u2.name);

//delete the local property "name" from u2
delete u2.name;

//neither u2 nor the prototype of u2 have a property name -> undefined
console.log(u2.name);

//add a property "name" to u1 (and thereby to the prototype of u2)
u1.name = 'tytus';

//prints "tytus" because u2 doesn't have a local property and therefor the property "name" of its prototype is used.
console.log(u2.name);
```