# Learning Array.prototype and calculating its length

Tags: javascript

**first:** I recently knew that `Array.prototype` is itself an array([]).But an amazing thing is that it is not the instance of Array object .How is that possible?What is the reason for this?

**Second:**`Array.prototype` has many properties but when u log i.e `console.log(Array.prototype.length)` ,the output is `'0'`.What is the reason here?I tried this aswell ,the result is same

```
var x=[];
x['a']="b";
x['b']="c";
console.log(x.length)//output:0
```

It would be great if u let me know the difference in element and property of an array

Comment: Well actually you first great x as array and the you are setting the properties to the x and this makes this as object try Object.keys(x)

Comment: This is a case of array vs object. Seems like you want to use an object here.

Comment: `var x = {};`, `[]` is an array, it doesn't accept named keys, only numeric ones(indexes) - then, to count number of keys, you can do as @jurka suggested!

Comment: @ALL could any one tell me the difference in array element and array property

Comment: @Maizere: to understand javascript semantics, read the [ECMA standard document](http://es5.github.io/), your question in particular is answered [here](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4)

Comment: @Maizere there is no such thing as "array propery", there are "array elements" and "object properties". Array is a special kind of object. `length` is a property of array object, which is updated by JS engine, and you should not write there. You also should not add properties to array, and should only use numberical indexes to read from array. For writing - use array literals, `push` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I recently knew that `Array.prototype` is itself an array (`[]`).

You are right, it is an array. The specification says in [§15.4.4, Properties of the Array Prototype Object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4):

> The Array prototype object is itself an array; its `[[Class]]` is `"Array"`, and it has a `length` property (whose initial value is `+0`) and the special `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method described in [15.4.5.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.1).

---

> But an amazing thing is that it is not the instance of Array object. How is that possible? What is the reason for this?

If you tried `Array.prototype instanceof Array` then the result will indeed be `false`. Why? Because of the way the `instanceof` operator works. It compares the prototype of an object with the value of the `prototype` property of the constructor function.
I.e. in this case it does

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype) === Array.prototype
```

As we can already see in this comparison, we are trying to test whether `Array.prototype` is its *own* prototype, which is impossible. The specification also mentions in the same paragraph:

> The value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the Array prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object ([15.2.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4)).

That is, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype) === Object.prototype` and `Object.prototype !== Array.prototype`. Hence `instanceof` yields `false`, but `Array.prototype` is an array nonetheless.

---

> `Array.prototype` has many properties but when u log i.e `console.log(Array.prototype.length)`, the output is '0'.

`0` being the value of `Array.prototype.length` is defined in specification (see above).

> It would be great if u let me know the difference in element and property of an array

An *element* of an array is a property with a property name that is a positive 32-bit integer (or `0`). A *property* is any other property which does not have such a property name. Those are not considered by any array operations.

The specification provides a more precise description in [§15.4, Array Objects](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4):

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name `P` (in the form of a String value) is an *array index* if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to `P` and `ToUint32(P)` is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1. A property whose property name is an array index is also called an *element*.

So you see, if a property name is converted to (the string representation of) an unsigned 32-bit integer and still has the same value, then it is an array index and the associated value is an element of the array.

The specification continuous with

> The value of the `length` property is numerically greater than the name of every property whose name is an array index;

We just learned which property names are considered to be array indexes, those that can be converted to unsigned integers. By that definition, `"a"` is not an array index, so

```
var x = [];
x['a'] = 42;
```

does not change the `length` property. But `"3"` is an array index, so

```
x["3"] = 42;
```

changes the `length` property to `4`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all objects in JavaScript inherit from other objects, not from constructor functions. Hence the statement *"But an amazing thing is that it is not the instance of Array object"* is wrong.

Say you have an object called `rectangle` as follows:

```
var rectangle = {
    height: 5,
    width: 10
};

rectangle.area = function () {
    return this.width * this.height;
};
```

Now I can calculate the area of this rectangle by calling the method `rectangle.area`. However say I wanted to create a new rectangle with a different `width` and `height`. This is what I would do:

```
var rectangle2 = Object.create(rectangle);

rectangle2.height = 8;
rectangle2.width = 20;

alert(rectangle2.area());
```

Here the object `rectangle2` inherits from the object `rectangle`. So you see objects actually inherit from other objects, not from constructor functions. Read the following thread for more details:

[Questions regarding prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17148615/783743)

When you precede a function call with the `new` keyword JavaScript creates a new object which inherits from the `prototype` of the function. Hence the instance actually inherits from the `prototype`.

**An object `a` only inherits from an object `b` if the object `b` is in the prototype chain of object `a`.** That's the reason we have the [`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) method.

---

The next thing to remember is that the `instanceof` operator doesn't really mean anything. It can be implemented in JavaScript as follows:

```
function instanceOf(obj, func) {
    return Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(func.prototype, obj);
}
```

Hence as you can clearly see an object qualifies as an *"instance"* of a function only if it inherits from the `prototype` of that function.

That's the reason why `Array.prototype instanceof Array` returns `false` - an object can't inherit from itself.

For more information about how the `instanceof` operator works read the following thread:

[JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8093057/783743)

---

Finally the `length` property of an array is always **one more than the greatest numeric index** of the array. For example:

```
var a = [];
alert(a.length); // 0
a[99999] = null;
alert(a.length); // 100000
```

That's the reason `Array.prototype.length` is `0` - `Array.prototype` has no numeric keys. However if you assign it a numeric key then the `length` property will change accordingly:

```
Array.prototype[99999] = null;
alert(Array.prototype.length); // 100000
```

The same applies for `x` - the properties `"a"` and `"b"` are not numeric. Hence they don't affect the `length` of the array.

---

BTW if you're interested in prototypal inheritance then you should read my blog post on [Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a variable as

```
var x=[];
x[0] = 0; or x[x.length]=0; or x.push(0);
```

its an array and it will have length property.
members of array can be referred using index(which is always numeric i.e.0,1,2, ...)

But when you create a variable as

```
var x={};
x.key1= "value1"; or x["key1"]="value1";
```

it becomes an object(JSON object). members of object will be always referred using keys.
like x.key1, x,key2 etc...

you can not access array members by x.0 or x.1 etc...

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

**To your first point:** Array is an object of type function.

```
console.log(Array);
function Array() { [native code] }
```

Array.prototype on the other hand, is an internal **implementation** of the methods shared between instances.

So,

```
console.log(Array.prototype);
[]
```

That's why `console.log(Array.prototype.length)` returns 0. It's an empty array.

Don't think of Array.protoype as an instance of Array. It's just an internal implementation on which you can call any method of the prototype object.

An instance can be created with the new operator. And all instances inherit the prototype object of the constructor function, in this case, Array.

```
var arr = new Array();
```

Hope it clarifies your first point.