# Isn't a prototype object an instance?

Tags: javascript

I have some code cannot understand.
Checked code below on smjs. I could not understand why false returned.
Isn't a prototype object an instance?

```
js> "".__proto__
(new String(""))
js> (new String("")) instanceof String
true
js> "".__proto__ instanceof String
false
```

Comment: `__proto__` isn't a String, its an Object

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky `String` is a type of object. He's talking about boxed string, not the value type.

Comment: The confusion might come from misinterpreting the first output. In your chosen JS engine the *string representation* of the prototype object is `'(new String(""))'`. That doesn't mean that `"".__proto__ === (new String(""))`.

Comment: @Juhana If you see my answer it links to the language specification. The language specification states that the string prototype is itself a string object. (=== wouldn't hold anyway since `String` objects (well, strings boxed) are not a value type.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, well, I didn't mean *literally* `===` (bad choice of symbol). Is it not possible that the JavaScript shell uses `(new String(""))` as a representation of the prototype object?

Comment: Ah, that sure is possible.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've got lost in the `"".__proto__.__proto__` part, seeing as `"".__proto__ === String.prototype`, how come `"".__proto__.__proto__` is an Object when `String.prototype.prototype` doesn't exist erm enough ecmas for a day.

Comment: This question is basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248437/learning-array-prototype-and-calculating-its-length

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used console of SpiderMonkey and when used console of Google Chrome, got same result. And this code below too.
`js> "".__proto__.constructor -> function String() { [native code] }`
So I have expected a prototype object of a String object is an instance of String. But not :(

Comment: Look at the question Pumbaa80 linked to. It really is the same. `String.prototype` **is** a string (according to the specification), but it is not an instance of the constructor function `String`. And because of the way `instanceof` works, it will return `false`. To quote the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4): *"The String prototype object is itself a String object (its [[Class]] is "String") whose value is an empty String. The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the String prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object (15.2.4)."*

Comment: Now it makes some sense, `String.prototype` and `"".__proto__` return a String object in my SpiderMonkey shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the same as [Learning Array.prototype and calculating its length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248437/learning-array-prototype-and-calculating-its-length).

`String.prototype` **is** a string, according to the specification, [§15.5.4, Properties of the String Prototype Object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4):

> The String prototype object is itself a String object (its `[[Class]]` is `"String"`) whose value is an empty String.
>
> The value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the String prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object ([15.2.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4)).

But it is not an instance of the constructor function `String`.

[`instanceof`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.6) works by comparing the prototype of the instance with the `prototype` property of the constructor function ([§15.3.5.3](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.3)), i.e.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(String.prototype) === String.prototype
```

So, you are testing whether `String.prototype` is it's *own* prototype, which is of course `false`. The prototype of `String.prototype` is, as mentioned in the specification, `Object.prototype`.

---

A word regarding the first example:

```
> js> "".__proto__
 (new String(""))
```

You have to keep in mind that the console (or RELP) uses some heuristic to format and present values. For example it might read the `constructor` property of the object to determine what "kind" of value it is and format the output accordingly. That's what the Chrome console is doing:

```
var str = new String('foo');
str instanceof String
=> true
console.dir(str);
=> String

var obj = {};
console.dir(obj);
=> Object                   // looks good

obj.constructor = String;
=> console.dir(obj); 
String                      // uhm what?
obj instanceof String
=> false
```

It happens that every prototype object has a `constructor` property, which points back to the function it is the prototype object of, i.e.

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo;
=> true
console.dir(Foo.prototype)
=> Foo
```

So if you log a prototype object, the output might suggest that the object is an instance of the function itself although it isn't, just because of the `constructor` property.

Comment: Hi, Felix. Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about implementation of instanceof operator for details. I understood clearly about result of my code :) But one more question. `But it is not an instance of the constructor function String.` If so, what kind of object String.prototype refers?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! `String.prototype` is still a string object but it was not constructed by calling `String`. See it as a string that was constructed *internally* in a different way.

Comment: I see. String.prototype is a string object but not an object created by using "new". It's created by using internal way. Thx!

Comment: You're welcome! If you find that an answer provided a solution to your question, please click on the checkmark next to it to "accept" it. This shows other users that that answer solved your problem.